# How to render the route name in an Ember.js application template?

Tags: ember.js

Given a list of routes:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'home', path: '/'
  @route 'sign-in'
  @route 'about'
```

How can I dynamically render this information into my application template (main layout)?

```
<div id="container" class="{{routeNameGoesHere}}">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

For example, fully rendered:

```
<div id="container" class="sign-in">
  <h1>Sign In Page</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Controllers automatically receive the properties `currentPath` and `currentRouteName` from the router.  So you can use those directly in your application template.

Comment: Do you know where I can find more information about these in the Ember docs?

Comment: @Andrew if that indeed works for you, a PR to the docs would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: Since I'm using this in a template as a CSS class, is it possible to replace dots with hyphens when `currentRouteName` is a nested route (with dot separators)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Grapho's answer, I found that I needed to create a computed property on my application controller in order to convert the dot-separated route names with dashes.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  hyphenatedCurrentRouteName: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function(){
    return this.get('currentRouteName').split('.').join('-')
  }
});
```

Now in my template, I can use `{{hyphenatedCurrentRouteName}}`.